# 'float' has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

For this program, you are supposed to enter the time and the meal you should eat will be the answer. e.g., between 7:00 and 8:00, the program will output "breakfast time". But, when I go to run the program, 'float' has no attribute 'split' is the error that I get. Help!

```
time = input("What time is it? ")
time = time.strip()
hours, minutes = time.split(":")
hours = float(hours)
minutes = float(minutes)


def convert(hours, minutes):
    #DEAL WITH ATTRIBUTE ERROR   
    #Split to the left and right of the decimal, multiply the small one by scientific notation to change the decimal. then add
    hours = hours.split(":")    #Convert float to string
    minutes = minutes.rsplit(":")
    minutes = minutes*10**-2

    if 7 <= hours < 9 and .0 <= minutes <= .59:
        print("breakfast time")
    if 12 <= hours < 13 and .0 <= minutes <= .59:
        print("lunch time")
    if 18 <= hours < 19 and .0 <= minutes <= .59:
        print("dinner time")
```

convert(hours, minutes)

Comment: You already split the time into its parts, and then make them floats, outside of the function. So why are you doing it again inside the function? And why do you think it will change a float to a string?

Comment: What decimal? `:` is a colon, `.` is decimal.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, it was old notes that I forgot to change.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `hours = hours.split(":")`, what do you think this means? What kind of thing should `hours` be before and after the code runs? Did you try to check that?

Answer (score -2):

Here the `time` arg has to be a sting like `7:45` and the result will be a output print (so without an actually return `-> None`)

```
def convert(time:str) -> None:
    """
    Enter time as 7:45
    """
    hours, minutes = map(int, time.strip().split(":")[:2])
    if 7 <= hours < 9 and 0 <= minutes <= 59:
        print("breakfast time")
    elif 12 <= hours < 13 and 0 <= minutes <= 59:
        print("lunch time")
    elif 18 <= hours < 19 and 0 <= minutes <= 59:
        print("dinner time")
    else:
        print("got nothing to eat ig")
```

Hope that helps.